# Postfix + Dovecot + Sieve + forwarding + sieve

Tags: postfix, dovecot, mail-forwarding, sieve

Let's suppose my domain at exampleserver.com.
I have following sieve rule:

```
require ["fileinto", "subaddress", "mailbox", "variables"];

if address :detail :matches "to" "*" {
set "folder" "${1}"; 
fileinto :create "INBOX.${folder}";
}
```

user@exampleserver.com wants mail forwarded to xxxxx@gmail.com. It is done via /etc/postfix/virtual as

```
user@exampleserver.com      xxxxx@gmail.com
```

The forwarding is perfectly good, but mail sent to user+Something@exampleserver.com is now forwarded to user+Something@gmail.com which is utterly wrong. How to fix it so sieved messages get redirected to xxxxx+Something@exampleserver.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix' aliasing via `virtual` is performed before any `sieve` proceeding. Therefore you have to disable postfix aliasing completely and forward messages by dovecot's sieve only. There is number of modes address is compared against the pattern:

```
......
# rule:[gmailfwd1]
if header :is "to" "user@exampleserver.com"
{
  redirect "user@gmail.com";
}

# rule:[gmailfwd2]
if header :contains "to" "user"
{
  redirect "otheruser@gmail.com";
}

# rule:[gmailfwd3]
if header :regex "to" "user.*@exampleserver.com"
{
  redirect "otheruser@gmail.com";
}
......
```

`header :is` means the strict matching the whole recipient's address

`header :contains` means that any part of address is matching the string.

`header :regex` means that recipient's address is matching the regular expression.

Anyway you have to remember that `sieve` rules are checked from the top to the bottom until some rule will be matched. So you can reorder rules in some sequence where more specific cases will be catched and proceeded before any other unwanted rules.

**P.S.**

As stated in the `dovecot`'s manual https://wiki.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Examples#Plus_Addressed_mail_filtering all can be made this way:

```
require ["variables", "fileinto", "subaddress"];

if header :is :user "to" "someuser" {
  if header :matches :detail "to" "*" {
    set "tag" "${1}";  /* extract "Something" into var "tag" */
  }

  if string :is "${tag}" "" { /* empty/no tag */
    redirect "user@gmail.com";
  } else {                    /* tag is present*/
    redirect "otheruser+${tag}@exampleserver.com";
  }
}
```

Comment: That yields invalid regular expression 'user(+.*)@exampleserver.com' for regex match: invalid preceding regular expression.

Comment: Have you added the plugin? `require ["fileinto","regex"....];`

Comment: Yes:require ["regex", "fileinto", "subaddress", "mailbox", "variables"];

Comment: I can't test it right now but it look like special meaning of `+` sign. Try to escape it by backslash `(\+.*)`

Comment: Didn't work. I tried to escape the parentheses as well but the result is still the same. If I use user(\\+.*)exampleserver.com  (double backslashes) the sievec doesn't give errors.

Comment: I've change my answer

Comment: I've test the first approach on my playground and it works ok. I've used `dovecot-2.3.1` and `pigeonhole-0.5.1`

Comment: Indeed it works - but there's a caveat. Now I must have matching user on my server. Let's say I want to provide an forwarding alias otheruser@exampleserver.com without such user on the server. Postfix will surely report: "Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table"

Comment: So you should explain your needs in details. Everything is possible with `sieve`

Comment: Well - I need to forward emails to another server (with the +)  without adding them as users to my server.

Comment: You can't do it with `sieve` because `sieve` proceed messages at the delivery stage. No user - no delivery - no sieving. I'm not familiar with `postfix` but `exim` is powerful enough to do anything we can imagine.